# formset validation in CBV

Tags: python, django

I have an Order form where I used formsets because I want the user to dynamically add more products and their quantity.
The user enters the name of the order, and it is validated not to be empty.
How do I validate the formset itself? to check that the product/quantity is not empty

## views.py

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    template_name = "orderform.html"
    fields = ['name', ]  
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(OrderCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['productmetas'] = InlineOrderFormSet(self.request.POST)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        productmetas = context['productmetas']
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        if productmetas.is_valid():
            productmetas.instance = self.object
            productmetas.save()

    return super(OrderCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

## models.py

```
class ProductMeta(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

## forms.py

```
InlineOrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Order, ProductMeta,
                                            form=OrderAutoCompleteForm,
                                            extra=1)
```

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/neara/6209563

Comment: Thanks, It works well. only thing I had to change was replace `commit_on_success` with `atomic`. `commit_on_success` is no longer part of `transaction`(when using django 1.11). I am using django-autocomplete-light for the formset and had to disable it to make the validation errors appear on the html. Do you know how I can make it work toghether with django-autocomplete-light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in the working solution for the question above
adapted from the answer by @neverwalkaloner

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    productmetas = context['productmetas']
    with transaction.atomic():
        self.object = form.save()
    if form.is_valid():
        if productmetas.is_valid():
            productmetas.instance = self.object
            productmetas.save()
        else:
            return super(OrderCreateView, self).form_invalid(form)

    return super(OrderCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```